# Can someone explain how to add a package in shared/src/commonMain/kotlin for a multiplatform mobile app using Ktor and SQLDelight?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

Problem with "Create a multiplatform app using Ktor and SQLDelight – tutorial"
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-ktor-sqldelight.html

Hi, on step "In shared/src/commonMain/kotlin, add the com.jetbrains.handson.kmm.shared.entity package" I do not understand - how add package?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84QXG.png)
I see only this actions [screen shot]. Please, help me

Comment: package is just a folder - you can simply select kotlin file, use `com.jetbrains.handson.kmm.shared.entity.Entity` and the package is gonna be created for you